# LibLas crashes when setting spatial reference manually

Tags: c++, crash, liblas

I am trying to set the spatial reference manually, but it is crashing.

```
std::ofstream ofs;
liblas::Header header;
liblas::SpatialReference srs;
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:4326"); // It crashes here
header.SetSRS(srs);
header.SetPointRecordsCount(1);
ofs.open("test.las", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
liblas::Writer writer(ofs, header);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of `liblas` are you using? What SO?

Comment: liblas version 1.8.0. THe SO is Windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has disappear after adding the environment variable.

GDAL_DATA "C:\OSGeo4W64\share\epsg_csv"